# How to select "a.my" as jquery in lift?

Tags: scala, css-selectors, lift

I want to select all `<a>` with class `my`in [liftweb](http://liftweb.net), and set its text to `???`:

```
val x = <div>
           <a><span class="my">xxx</span></a>
           <a class="my">yyy</a>
        </div>
```

I tried:

```
"a .my *" #> "???"
```

and

```
"a" #> (".my *" #> "???")
```

But neither works, because both of them convert the `x` to:

```
 <div>
    <a><span class="my">???</span></a>
    <a class="my">???</a>
 </div>
```

Which are incorrect, they should only convert the second `<a>`.

What's the correct code?

Comment: The question is unclear. `<a><span class="my">mytext</span></a>` is not an `a.my` because the `<a>` does not have class `my`. Did you mean `a .my`?

Comment: @MattBall,thank you, I just updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no direct way to do that using Lift 2.5 and earlier. I believe they will be adding support for that more robust type of binding to Lift 3, but since it is not here yet you will need to work around it.

Since you can work directly with the `NodeSeq` on the right of the `CssSelector`, something like this should allow you to accomplish what you are looking to do:

```
"a" #> { ns:NodeSeq => 
  if((ns \ "@class").text == "my")
    ("* *" #> "???").apply(ns)
  else 
    ns 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was fighting for another problem, I read this again(https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/binding_via_css_selectors) and I found a solution.

just use

```
".my" #> ("a *" #> "???")
```

instead of

```
"a" #> (".my *" #> "???")
```

then everything goes well